# Weird colored stripes around windows - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, unity, nvidia, graphics

So recently I noticed that, around the windows, and the right click menu of all applications, there are these weird colored stripes. They disappear after I restart Ubuntu or Unity, but then appear again shortly after.

[Colored stripes around terminal windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4axTn.jpg)

My laptop used NVIDIA GeForce 960M, and for those who knows, I just started CUDA programming a few weeks ago.

These are the installed packages related to nvidia:

```
quan@quantran:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep nvidia

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

nvidia-367/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-367-dev/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-375/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-375-dev/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-dev/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-doc/xenial,xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-gdb/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-toolkit/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-modprobe/unknown,now 367.48-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-dev/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-367/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-375/xenial,now 375.39-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/xenial,now 0.8.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-profiler/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/xenial,now 378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-visual-profiler/xenial,now 7.5.18-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Result of `lspci`:

```
quan@quantran:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: This is a bug with `nvidia-375`. Remove the PPA and install the official `nvidia-367`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is indeed the new version of the NVidia driver. Reverting to 375 doesn't work because IMHO it has also been updated (minor version) and/or its dependencies are a mix of several versions. Anyway:

1. Remove the PPA. On my computer I deleted the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` pointing to the repository `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main`
2. Remove all the installed NVidia packages, i.e. `nvidia-*`. On my computer I deleted several packages with `apt remove nvidia-361 nvidia-375 nvidia-378`
3. Update the packages list with `apt update`
4. Install the last official version (i.e. 367) with `apt install nvidia-367`

As a side note, I'm always amazed how updates regularly break Ubuntu...